# PECL install fails with Invalid tgz file

Tags: php, pear, pecl

I have two vagrant instances, running Ubuntu 16.04.
One is a development machine we have been using for development of our software for quite some time. The other one is a pretty clean install, set up just to test this.

I run this command in both servers:

`sudo pecl install grpc`

On the development server, where we have lots of other things going on, I get this output:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ sudo pecl install grpc
downloading grpc-1.27.0.tgz ...
Starting to download grpc-1.27.0.tgz (3,196,501 bytes) 
......................................................................
done: 3,196,501 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/tmp/pear/download/grpc-1.27.0.tgz". 
Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/grpc" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/grpc"
Download failed
install failed
```

On the clean machine it works just fine, and the install runs smoothly.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a solution. On a hunch I tried to `chmod -R 777 /tmp`, and run the install command again.

Worked like a charm.